# Lasso select points from matplotlib plot: colours change when selecting

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to select points using a lasso tool from a matplotlib scatter plot. A demo is shown here:

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/widgets/lasso_selector_demo_sgskip.html

In the example, all the scatter points have the same color. I have a scatter plot with varying colour, although that should not make a difference. Here is my code:

```
xvals = [pt[0] for pt in list(positions.values())]
yvals = [pt[1] for pt in list(positions.values())]

nr_colors=10

subplot_kw = dict(xlim=(min(xvals), max(xvals)), ylim=(min(yvals), max(yvals)), autoscale_on=False)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=subplot_kw)
pts = ax.scatter(x=xvals,y=yvals,c=coloring,s=sizing/15000,cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap("RdYlGn"))

selector = lassoselector.SelectFromCollection(ax, pts)

def accept(event):
    if event.key == "enter":        
        selector.pointslist.append(selector.ind)
        print("Appended a cluster!")
    elif event.key == "1":
        selector.disconnect()
        ax.set_title("")
        fig.canvas.draw()
        plt.close()
        print("Analyzing clusters...")
        vals=[]
        for selected_rows in selector.pointslist:
            vals.append(np.mean(whereUsed.T.values[selected_rows],axis=0))

        diff = vals[0]-vals[1]
        df = pd.DataFrame({"Difference":diff})
        df.index = dimension_value_names
        df.sort_values(by="Difference",ascending=True).plot(kind="barh",legend=False,title="Cluster 1 - Cluster 2",figsize=(10,15))




fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", accept)
ax.set_title("Press enter to accept selected points, press 1 to close")

plt.show()
```

As you can see the code is quite similar to the example. Only difference is that my pts object contains many colors instead of just one. So, when accessing the colours in the class through:

```
    self.fc = collection.get_facecolors()
```

I should get my colour list. For some reason, this is not working and self.fc only contains one colour (blue) when I start drawing. Turning the whole image to blue and a lighter shaded blue, as in the example. How can I keep my original colours and just fade out the selection I'm not using?

Comment: Without being able to run your code, it is hard to tell what is going wrong. What class are you talking about? There is no class defined in your code!

Comment: I suggest that you modify the demo code in such a way that it reproduces the problem and post that code instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bug.

If you run it in interactive mode it does not change the facecolors to blue. In the sense of first creating the figure with the scatter, and then initialising the selector.
It seams that the facecolors from the collection are not populated until the figure is actually drawn, if the selector is called before the figure is drawn, then the get_facecolors() method will return the default color (blue).

I did a workaround that may not be pretty but it does the trick. Basically I included a optional parameter to the SelectFromCollection class such that instead of getting the facecolors from the collection, it uses the parameter. I included the whole code below for reference.
The main change to the class is the line:
if facecolors is not None: self.fc = facecolors

'''

```
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.widgets import LassoSelector
from matplotlib.path import Path


class SelectFromCollection(object):
    # Select indices from a matplotlib collection using `LassoSelector`.
    #
    # Selected indices are saved in the `ind` attribute. This tool fades out the
    # points that are not part of the selection (i.e., reduces their alpha
    # values). If your collection has alpha < 1, this tool will permanently
    # alter the alpha values.
    #
    # Note that this tool selects collection objects based on their *origins*
    # (i.e., `offsets`).
    #
    # Parameters
    # ----------
    # ax : :class:`~matplotlib.axes.Axes`
    #     Axes to interact with.
    #
    # collection : :class:`matplotlib.collections.Collection` subclass
    #     Collection you want to select from.
    #
    # alpha_other : 0 <= float <= 1
    #     To highlight a selection, this tool sets all selected points to an
    #     alpha value of 1 and non-selected points to `alpha_other`.
    #

    def __init__(self, ax, collection, alpha_other=0.3, facecolors=None):
        self.canvas = ax.figure.canvas
        self.collection = collection
        self.alpha_other = alpha_other

        self.xys = collection.get_offsets()
        self.Npts = len(self.xys)

        # Ensure that we have separate colors for each object
        self.fc = collection.get_facecolors()
        if len(self.fc) == 0:
            raise ValueError('Collection must have a facecolor')
        elif len(self.fc) == 1:
            self.fc = np.tile(self.fc, (self.Npts, 1))

        if facecolors is not None: self.fc = facecolors

        self.lasso = LassoSelector(ax, onselect=self.onselect)
        self.ind = []

    def onselect(self, verts):
        path = Path(verts)
        self.ind = np.nonzero(path.contains_points(self.xys))[0]
        self.fc[:, -1] = self.alpha_other
        self.fc[self.ind, -1] = 1
        self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

    def disconnect(self):
        self.lasso.disconnect_events()
        self.fc[:, -1] = 1
        self.collection.set_facecolors(self.fc)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    # Fixing random state for reproducibility
    np.random.seed(19680801)

    data = np.random.rand(100, 100)
    x_2d = np.zeros((100,100))
    y_2d = np.zeros((100,100))
    for r_ in range(100):
        x_2d[r_,:] = np.arange(100)
        y_2d[:,r_] = np.arange(100)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    pts = ax.scatter(x_2d.flatten(), y_2d.flatten(), c=data.flatten(), cmap=plt.cm.jet)
    facecolors = plt.cm.jet(data.flatten())
    selector = SelectFromCollection(ax, pts, facecolors=facecolors)

    def accept(event):
        if event.key == "enter":
            print("Selected points:")
            print(selector.xys[selector.ind])
            selector.disconnect()
            ax.set_title("")
            fig.canvas.draw()

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", accept)
    ax.set_title("Press enter to accept selected points.")

    plt.show()
```

'''